# How to pass values of two different select tags for process using Ajax and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**HTML :**

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="dog">dog</option>
    <option value="cat">cat</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2">
    <option value="chocolate">chocolate</option>
    <option value="pizza">pizza</option>
</select>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#sel').change(function(){
   var index = $("option:selected",this).attr("value");

   $.get("topperprocess.php",{semester_name:index},
        function(data)
        {
           $("div#toppersdata").html(data);
        }
   );
});
```

This code works very well for a single select tag but I want to use two select tag and there value is passed for process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by getting the value of selected option in the both selects and send it as parameter of `get` request `{sel: sel, sel2: sel2}` :

```
$('#sel,#sel2').change(function(){
     var sel  = $("#sel option:selected").val();
     var sel2 = $("#sel option:selected").val();

     $.get("topperprocess.php",{sel: sel, sel2: sel2},
         function(data){
             $("div#toppersdata").html(data);
         }
     );
 });
```

Get the values in your php page using `$_GET` :

```
$select1_value = $_GET['sel'];
$select2_value = $_GET['sel2'];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectChanged = function() {
    var index = $('#sel').val();
    var index2 = $('#sel2').val();

    $.get(
        "topperprocess.php",
        {
            semester_name: index,
            semester_name2: index2
        },
        function(data){
            $("div#toppersdata").html(data);
        }
    );
}

$('#sel,#sel2').change(selectChanged);
```

It is a little confusing as to exactly what you want to do. But there are a few modifications that I made that I think will help you out.

1) If you want the exactly same thing to happen for both select boxes, you should create **1 function** that is used by both events. Here, you can see I've created `selectChanged`. This will be called by the `change` event of both `#sel` and `#sel2`.

2) We can retrieve the value of a select box using the `.val()` function of a select or other input element. We don't need to search for the select option manually.

3) Of course, we send both the values we've retrieved to the server in the object. You're sure you don't want to use a `POST`, right?